# GeneratedPluginRegistrant module "app_links" not found

Tags: flutter, xcode

When I try to build my flutter app for my iPhone through xcode I get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVQ9E.png)

I've changed the iOS target to match in cocopods and In xcode but did not help, I've also tried reinstalling cocoapods incase It was the problem but to no help.

Comment: fyi when I build to my android it works without any problems.

Comment: Are your pods installing as required?

Comment: Not quite sure, the files are in the project but I'm quite new to this. I do get this message when i run pod install
`Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total pods installed.`

Answer (score 0):

This could be a pods related issue. Please try this

```
//make sure you are in the ios folder
$flutter clean 
...
then
$flutter pub get
///then initialise pods
$pod init
..
$pod install
//Then build for ios
```

Comment: I did this and got a new error message but when i installed the pods,

`The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Debug.xcconfig`).`

Comment: Just ignore the error amd proceed to build the ios version

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following and try to re run your app

```
rm Podfile.lock
pod cache clean --all
sudo arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
pod repo update
pod install
```

It will take a while but this syncs your podfile by downloading all of your dependencies again. Sometimes happens after updating your mac's OS or updating flutter.